# Observer block never working in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

The observer block was introduced a while back, and I was never able to make it work. Now, I saw someone do a tutorial on how to observer blocks, and for me the observer would never send block updates with redstone pulses. Am I really not doing this right? I know the block only sends a one second redstone pulse, but that never happened in my case. (I am on 1.14.1)

Here's what I've tried: (And I have looked online to no avail.)
[image: Auto Sugar Farm not working]
[image: Simple block update not working]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the block back-to-front.

This side of the block should be facing the object you are trying to detect an update:

[image]

The redstone signal then travels in the direction of the arrow on top, to the back of the block with the red dot.

Think of it this way: the Observer needs to "see" with its "face", in order to "observe" an update.

Answer (score -1):

The observer is facing the wrong way. The arrow on the observer always has to face the direction the redstone pulse goes. You must let the observer"s "face" point towards the sugarcane.